# How to use Wireshark to get the bitrate of an online video

Tags: wireshark, bitrate

For example, set the resolution to auto and let the online video plays,
How can I measure the bit rate of this video transmission?
I've captured a pcapng file, it should be under TCP, but which ones are transmitting video clips? How should I check?